# Enclosing an iterable in a generator expression changes the order that contexts are cleaned up

Tags: python, exception, generator, iterable

I have a Python application which has two nested `with` blocks, one of which occurs inside an object's `__iter__` method. I have observed that wrapping the iterable object inside a generator expression changes the order these `with` blocks are finalised when an exception is raised, and I am very surprised by this.

I am using python 3.11.5 but have observed the same behaviour in 3.8.17.

Here is a demonstrator which reproduces the observed behaviour as well as the expected behaviour:

```
from contextlib import closing, contextmanager


class Reader:
    def close(self):
        print(f"CLOSE: {self.__class__.__name__}")

    @contextmanager
    def get_resource(self):
        try:
            yield 42
        finally:
            print(f"CLOSE: {self.__class__.__name__} releases resource")


class Container:
    def __init__(self, reader: Reader):
        self._reader = reader

    def __iter__(self):
        with self._reader.get_resource() as resource:
            for x in range(10):
                yield x


def my_code():
    with closing(Reader()) as reader:
        container = Container(reader)
        container_gen = (x for x in container)
        for thing in container_gen:
            assert False


def expected():
    with closing(Reader()) as reader:
        container = Container(reader)
        for thing in container:
            assert False


print(">>> What my code does:")
try:
    my_code()
except AssertionError:
    print("handle exception")

print()

print(">>> The context handling I expected:")
try:
    expected()
except AssertionError:
    print("handle exception")
```

This is the output I get from this code:

```
>>> What my code does:
CLOSE: Reader
handle exception
CLOSE: Reader releases resource

>>> The context handling I expected:
CLOSE: Reader releases resource
CLOSE: Reader
handle exception
```

It seems that wrapping the `Container` in a generator expression causes the `with` block in its `__iter__` method to be cleaned up after the exception handling is complete, despite the fact that it's nested within another `with` block that gets cleaned up while the exception is being raised.

Why does wrapping the iterable in a generator expression change how the `with` block inside its `__iter__` method is finalised during exception handling?

#### EDIT:

Thanks to the answer from [@user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) I see that omitting the local variable bound to the generator expression gives the context handling I expected:

```
def my_code_without_local():
    with closing(Reader()) as reader:
        container = Container(reader)
        for thing in (x for x in container):
            assert False
```

This gives this output:

```
CLOSE: Reader releases resource
CLOSE: Reader
handle exception
```

This behaviour is really surprising to me, as I expected the active `with`-block in the named generator expression `container_gen` to be cleaned up in the same way as the active `with`-block in `my_code`, not that it would hang around and only get cleaned up once the local name `container_gen` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on a `with` in a generator, and those are awkward, because cleanup can easily get delayed like this. Specifically, I'm talking about your `__iter__` method, which you wrote as a generator. Not the genexp - I'll get to that later.

If you don't fully loop over your `__iter__` generator, the `with` block cleanup only runs when the generator is `close`d. Like most people, you never explicitly closed your generator. You probably never even thought about it. The only time it gets closed is in the generator's `__del__` method, which gets called when Python determines the generator is unreachable.

With `expected`, the only reference to your `__iter__` generator is the internal reference the `for` loop keeps to its iterator. That reference dies before the `with closing(Reader()) as reader:` block is exited, and since CPython has reference counting, the interpreter immediately detects that the generator is unreachable, so it calls `__del__`, triggering the cleanup you expected. (On a non-refcounting implementation, like PyPy, this cleanup wouldn't be so prompt.)

With `my_code`, your `__iter__` generator is reachable from the generator created by your genexp, which is reachable through the `container_gen` local variable. That local variable is reachable through the exception traceback, so it doesn't get cleared until the `except` block finishes and the exception object dies. (This is true even though your `except` block doesn't have an `as` clause - the exception and its traceback are still available through [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) during the `except` block.)

Your generator ends up living much longer than you expected it to. Since the cleanup you were expecting only gets triggered by the generator's `__del__` method, the cleanup gets delayed just as long.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! If I understand correctly, you're saying that the `with` in the generator, when wrapped in the genexp, is handled differently to the `with` in `my_code` because `with` blocks in genexp's are only finalised when the genexp is closed, and that my genexp isn't closed until after the exception is handled because there is a reference to it that is reachable through the traceback. Is that correct?

Comment: @AdamTuft: If you looped over your generator fully, execution would naturally exit the `with` and trigger cleanup at that point. Since iteration never completes, the `with` cleanup only gets triggered when the generator is closed, and that gets heavily delayed due to the traceback extending the `container_gen` variable's lifetime.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why is the `with` cleanup *only* triggered when the named genexp is closed, and not by the exception that is raised during iteration of the genexp? As you explained, the expected behaviour is observed when the genexp **isn't** named (as in the example I added to my question) which is really surprising to me.

Comment: @AdamTuft: The generator's stack frame isn't on the stack when the exception occurs. The exception never propagates through the generator. It's not like Ruby `yield`. Where Ruby `yield` invokes a block, adding a frame to the stack, Python `yield` suspends a generator, *removing* its stack frame from the stack.

Comment: The suspended generator function does take part in the exception unwinding, though, doesn't it? Isn't that what's happening in the `expected` function? The `__iter__` method is evaluated once, the `with` block is entered and then the generator is suspended at the `yield`, and after the exception is raised the `with`-block is finalised as expected. What seems to change this behaviour is whether the generator function is enclosed in a named generator expression, which seems like a really odd effect.

Comment: @AdamTuft: Nope. The suspended generator isn't involved in the exception unwinding process. The generator just dies earlier in `expected`, because there's no local variable keeping it alive.

Comment: I think I understand now... So in the `expected` code the `with` block in `__iter__` is only finalised in the expected order by accident, due to the generator going out of scope and being closed at the moment the exception is raised. It isn't actually participating in the unwinding of the stack during the exception propagation, even though it appears that way.